# How to open file in specified app in iOS?

Tags: ios, file

I know  the UIWebview,UIDocumentInteractionController，QLPreviewController can  do the fileview  work of office files,  i want to view  the office file in a better way the

```
[self.docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.frame  inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

can show all apps can open the file , how can i choose the specified one  automatically

Comment: Take a look at app-specific URL schemes.

Comment: I know the specific URL schemes can  open the app ,but how can I send file to the app,when I open it ? I want to open the  doc file with  "Word" app  automatically @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/the4kman